# Error mapping fftw complex to Eigen matrix

Tags: c++, eigen, fftw, reinterpret-cast

I have the following code where I am using both libraries Eigen and FFTW in C++. I am aware of the unsuported FFT that Eigen has, but I am using the FFTW library for additional features. So, I am trying to take the FFT with a C++ array and then map the output to a complex Eigen matrix (to perform some linear algebra operations on it). I have the code:

```
struct cplx_buffer
{
  fftw_complex* a;
  int rows;
  int cols;

  fftw_complex& operator()(int i, int j) const { return a[i * cols + j]; }
};
struct real_buffer
{
  double* a;
  int rows;
  int cols;

  double& operator()(int i, int j) const { return a[i * cols + j]; }
};
int main(){ 

static const int nx = 10;
static const int ny = 10; 
static const int nyk = ny/2 + 1;
static const int mm = nx* 3/2;



cplx_buffer outW = my_fftw_allocate_cplx((ny+1), mm); 

real_buffer inW = my_fftw_allocate_real((ny+1), mm);

//initialize the input
    for (int i = 0; i < ny+1; i++){ 
        for (int j = 0; j < mm; j++){ 
            inW(i,j) = //expression
        }
    
    }
//Take FFT of rows
     { // Transform all the rows
    fftw_execute(fftw_plan_many_dft_r2c(1, &nx, inW.rows, inW.a, &inW.cols, 1, inW.cols, outW.a, &inW.cols, 1, outW.cols, FFTW_ESTIMATE));
    }

    Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXcd, Eigen::Unaligned> invnek(*reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(&outW),(ny+1),mm); //ERROR
}
```

The error:

```
no instance of constructor "Eigen::Map<PlainObjectType, MapOptions, StrideType>::Map [with PlainObjectType=Eigen::MatrixXcd, MapOptions=0, StrideType=Eigen::Stride<0, 0>]" matches the argument list
```

How can I `reinterpret_cast` here correctly?

Comment: ```reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(…)``` Also, remove that asterisk

Comment: why these two are different and return different results?
``Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXcd,Eigen::Unaligned>test(reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(u),(ny+1),mm);`` and this
``Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXcd,Eigen::Unaligned>test(reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(&u),(ny+1),mm); 
 ``

Comment: The second takes a pointer of ```u``` with ```&u```. That only makes sense if ```u``` is a scalar value or a reference. For example if the type of ```u``` is ```fftw_complex*```, use the first variant. If the type is ```fftw_complex&```, use the second.

Comment: The thing is when I use the second expression for the above example my result is off and why is that, b/c my ``cplx_buffer`` is defined as ``fftw_complex*`` so it should be mapped correctly.

Comment: Your code doesn't show a ```u``` variable. What your code does show is ```*reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(&outW)``` which references the ```struct cplx_buffer```, not the array within. Change it to ```reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(outW.a)```